# How do I format FusionCharts time to include seconds?

Tags: c#, fusioncharts, multivariate-time-series

##### My problem

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now. My chart is seeing the values its being provided. I can tell because the range of chart has an upper limit of 60k, but it doesn't seem to be reading my timestamps correctly, so the chart's domain runs from 1 Jan 1970 02:00:00 to 1 Jan 1970 02:00:00 (I'm in GMT+2). So, I am not sure if this is a formatting issue in my schema, or the data that I'm providing.

I am using the ASP.NET integration for this.

My schema:

```
let schema = [{
            'name': 'Time',
            'type': 'date',
            'format': '%Y-%m-%d %I:%-m:%-S'
        },{
            'name': 'value1',
            'type': 'number'
        }]
```

My data:

```
let data = [
            ['2023-11-28 10:00:00',60000],
            ['2023-11-28 10:01:03',59304],
            ['2023-11-28 10:02:01',59943]
           ]
```

My timestamp is in the following format:
`2001-01-31 00:00:00.000`

##### Things I have tried

- Appending `.%-L` to my format to account for the milliseconds, but that didn't change anything
- Passing the date as a `new Date(date)` in the JSON object
- Changing the date format to `2001-01-31T00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was.

In the database, the format time is formatted `2001-01-31 23:00:59.000`, but when the data is passed to the front, it becomes `2001/01/31 23:00:59`.

So, from this, the format in the schema has to be `'%Y/%m/%d %I:%-M:%-S'`